# Casting in foreach loop

Tags: c#

I ran into the following code:

```
foreach (var row in datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
  some code here
}
```

Now, I think casting in a foreach loop is incorrect, since I think it cast each time it loops. But, I could be wrong, maybe the compiler is smart enough?

On a related note: How can I figure something like this out for myself?

Comment: To find out for yourself you could download some decompiler and check the actual source. My favorite is [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) from JetBrains (from the makers of Re#). There is also [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) which is very popular

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it *calls* `Cast<DataRow>` once, but that will actually cast each item as it's fetched. So there *is* a cast on each iteration (at least potentially; `Cast` has an optimization when it knows it's not necessary) but there's only a single method call. The iterator returned by `Cast` will fetch items (lazily) from the source (`datatable.Rows` here) and cast each item as it's requested by the loop.

See my [Edulinq post on `Cast`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype.aspx) for more information.

Although the waters are a bit muddied here due to `Cast` being lazy, it's important to remember that the expression to the right of `in` is only ever evaluated once. So a loop of the form:

```
foreach (var item in complicatedExpression)
{
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
var items = complicatedExpression;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    ...
}
```

The compiler will generate code that calls `GetEnumerator()` *once*, and then uses the result of that to iterate over the collection.

For this specific example, an alternative to using `Cast` would be to let the compiler put the cast in the loop itself:

```
foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
{
  some code here
}
```

The compiler will perform a cast on each item as it fetches it from the iterator, implicitly. It's a bit sneaky because it's not *obviously* casting.

As for how you can tell what's going on - you could always use `ildasm` to look at the IL. That can be very instructive, but somewhat time-consuming.

Comment: I was actually thinking I had to move the cast out of the loop, to put it in front of it.

Comment: The last hidden cast example is very crucial as I always assumed that the var in foreach loop is type-checked, until I run into a bug that triggered an `InvalidCastException` on the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `IEnumerable<T>.Cast<TResult>` extension method returns an enumerable thats lazily evaluated. This means that every time you request the 'next' item from it, it retrieves it from the underlying datasource (the datatable in your case), and casts it to the specified type. So casting in a `foreach` is not incorrect, since the casting is not done 'too much', it is done for every item, when it is necessary. Adding a `.ToList()` is not better, since this garantuees to cast **every item**, even when you not need to, for example, if you exit the loop with a `break`.

You can find this out yourself by reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and reading articles about the method.

Answer (score 0):

When you have:

```
foreach(SomeType name in {expression})
{
    // your code
}
```

the `{expression}` is **only evaluated once**, so in your example, `Cast<DataRow>()` is only invoked once. The result of `{expression}` is then processed for enumeration, becoming something like (depending on a lot of things, such as what APIs the result of `{expression}` supports):

```
using(var iter = {expression}.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(iter.MoveNext()
    {
        SomeType name = iter.Current; // location on recent compilers
        // your code
    }
}
```